# How to check the HTML element is a end node?

Tags: perl, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I am building a HTML parser in Perl. I would like to know if the HTML element is an element without any sibilings.

Here is the HTML, I would like to parse :

```
<span class="bold1">A:</span> ELementA<br />
<span class="bold1">B:</span> <a href="mailto:admin" class="bold1">mailto:admin</a><br />
<span class="bold1">C </span> 01/12<br />
<span class="bold1">D:</span> ELementC<br />
<span class="bold1">E:</span> ElementD<br />
<span class="bold1">F:</span> ElementE<br />
```

How to check if the element is the end element.

I am getting the error :

```
Can't call method "as_text" without a package or object reference at
```

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Here is the code snippet in Perl,

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );

eval 
{
    $mech->get($url);
};
if ($@) 
{
    print "Error connecting to URL $url \n";
    exit(0);
}

my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(decode_utf8($mech->content));

my @PageSections = $root->look_down( 
            sub { 
                return (
                ($_[0]->tag() eq 'span' ) and 
                ($_[0]->attr('class')  =~ m/bold1/i) )

            }); 

my $temp2;
my $temp3;

for my $ps (@PageSections)
{
    #  my $temp1= $ps->right()->as_text;
    $temp2= $ps->as_text;

    my $temp3=ref $ps->right();
    # 
    print defined $temp3 ? "defined \n" : "not defined\n";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using [HTML-Tree](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tree/)?

Comment: NO, I am using HTML::Treebuilder

Comment: [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder) is part of the [HTML-Tree](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tree/) distribution (as you'd have seen if you'd clicked on the link), so you _are_ using HTML-Tree.  (Also, Perl is case-sensitive, so it's HTML::TreeBuilder, not HTML::Treebuilder.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without knowing more of your code, but I'm guessing @PageSections contains objects of some home brewed module, and that something happens there to make $_ point to something completely different. I'd go with

```
for my $ps (@PageSections)
{
    my $temp1= $ps->right()->as_text;
    my $temp2= $ps->as_text;
    print "$temp2  " . $temp1 . " \n";
}
```

instead.

Comment: This did not help actually, I have defined Pagesection as something like this : my @PageSections = $root->look_down('class' => qr/bold1$/);

Comment: I just googled the methods you're using, and it seems like you are using HTML::TreeBuilder? It wouldn't hurt to include that in your question. It also doesn't say where the error occurs. I'm going to guess that it fails on `my $temp1= $ps->right()->as_text;` because right() returns undef. Try writing `my $temp0= $ps->right();print defined $temp0 ? "defined\n" : "not defined\n";
`

Comment: Yes, I am using the HTML::Treebuilder, I am not an expert, I will print right after checking your suggestion.

Comment: I am updating the question with the added code. It did not change, $temp0 shows as defined always

Comment: Try to print ref($_), ref($_->right) and ref($_->right()->as_text) to see what kind of objects they're pointing at then.

Comment: No problem. I just ran the code myself, and the reason it doesn't work is because after the first span, right() returns the text node containing " ELementA" returned as a scalar, which obviously won't have the method as_text(). Might want to include `unless ref($_->right())` or something somewhere in there